# What is the correct way to speak about salary bonuses?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to ask about the generic term for money that an employer pays but is not contractually required to pay. For example, they can give a motivational payment or a payment for expenditure reimbursement. I found the word "allowance," but it seems like you have to get money regularly to call it that. I'm looking for a more general word for money that isn't mentioned in the contract.

Comment: What's wrong with _salary bonuses_?

Comment: Maybe everything is correct. Can I call "travel reimbursements," for example, a salary bonus?

Comment: Travel reimbursements are not by any stretch of the word a salary bonus.

Comment: I really don't think there is a single word that covers both travel reimbursements and salary bonuses (i.e., extra money that you get paid on top of your salary for doing a good job).

Comment: Employers are normally required to pay expense reimbursements, at least if contractually specified. In the question you should list the sort of payments you want to include, and the sorts you want to exclude.

Comment: You could group all monies that aren't wages under *benefits*. Reimbursements are likely to be contractual, while bonuses are completely optional.

Comment: Taxables and nontaxables are not usually lumped together.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, but then *benefits* may be too broad, because it includes in-kind benefits (which have monetary value but are not literally paid to the employee).

Comment: Some of the OP's confusion regarding reimbursements may be due to the fact that some of the expenses that employers readily reimburse to higher-level managerial employees (such as first-class travel, stays in luxury hotels, and meals in expensive restaurants) are perceived by the general public as perks of their positions, even though the law regards these expenses as incurred for the benefit of the employers and not for for the indulgence of the employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you pay someone funds, you are making a **disbursement**.

> funds paid out

This includes incentive bonuses, retention bonuses, paychecks, reimbursements, or any other reason you give funds to an employee, non-employee or any entity. It covers contractually obligated payments as well. To remove that from the definition, you can qualify these as *non-contractual* disbursements.

FYI, reimbursing someone for expenses *is* typically contractual.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disbursement)

Comment: It is puzzling that the OP has accepted this answer, because the word, as the answer makes clear, covers the payments, such as regular paychecks, that the question explicitly sought to exclude.

Comment: @jsw29 I have accepted this answer due to "non-contractual disbursements." The discussion below the question made it clear that there is no one-word term for this; therefore, I accepted an answer that consists of several words. Thank you all for the discussion.

Comment: @Vash, note that *non-contractual* implies that the payment is entirely gratuitous, which is relatively rare in employment settings. You seem to be missing that something can be contractual in nature even though it is not, as you put it in the question 'mentioned in the contract', by which you presumably mean the contract creating the employment relationship. If your boss sends you somewhere and tells you 'To get there faster, take a taxi; we'll reimburse you' that is **a** contract, even though it is not a part of **the** contract that made you an employee of that business.